# can I specify tags subject and body in search?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

Can I do a search on stackoverflow for all posts with a certain tag, and with a certain thing in the subject and body? e.g.  if i'm looking for vbscript sendkeys unicode.. The tag would be vbscript, but sendkeys is just a function, and unicode is in relation to sendkeys. So i'd really want vbscript in the tag, and sendkeys and unicode in the subject.  can I do such a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check out the [search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

Something like this (not sure about the intitle syntax):

```
[vbscript] intitle:sendkeys unicode
```

I submit to you though that searcjhing in the question title explicity will hardly make sense, except if you are searching for a specific post.

Comment: Thanks.. search ref page is especially useful.. I see it comes up when entering nothing and pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just enclose the tags in square brackets.  So for your example, type

```
[vbscript] sendkeys unicode
```

in the search box.